# Is f Lesbegue Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I've got a problem that I have been working on in my Real Analysis class, and am not sure on the answer. The problem is below along with my thoughts so far.

Problem:
Let f be a function such that $f(x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ for x $\in [n, n+1)$. Is f Lebesgue integrable on $[1,\infty)$?

My thoughts:
In class we learned that a function is Lebesgue integrable if $\int_E f^+$ and $\int_E f^-$ are finite, where $f^+=max\{f,0\}$ and $f^-=max\{-f,0\}$.

Since it can be shown that $$\int_{[1,\infty)}f^+=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[1,n]}f^+=lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}$$
and the sum diverges, I am thinking that f is not Lebesgue integrable. Is my reasoning on this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $|f|$ is, because as you mention, you define the integral using $f^+$ and $f^-$, both of which have to be finite.

Since $|f|=f^++f^-$, the function you give has  $ |f(x)|= \frac{1}{n}$ on $[n,n+1)$, and we know $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks! It was throwing me off because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[1,n]}f$ exists.